# Unhandled exception in program for blending of an array

Tags: c

I got some issues with my program, there aren't any compiling errors. I get "Unhandled exception at 0x00d114d6 in ALINUR_CAGLAYAN_LAB6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000006." error after I enter array elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main(void)

{
float *newArray, *blendingArray;
int a, x, blendingLength;

printf("length: ");
scanf("%d", &blendingLength);

blendingArray = (float*)malloc(blendingLength*sizeof(float));
newArray = (float*)malloc(blendingLength*sizeof(float));

for(a=0; a<blendingLength; a++)
{
printf("%d. element", a+1);
scanf("%d", &blendingArray);
}

for(a=0; a < blendingLength; a++)
{
    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
        newArray[a]=blendingArray[a];
    }
    else if (a % 2 == 1)
    {
        newArray[a]=blendingArray[blendingLength - a];
    }
}
for (a=0; a < blendingLength; a++)
{
printf("%d. element of new array: %d\n", a+1, newArray[a]);
}
return *newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading integer values into the `blendingArray` pointer, repeatedly. Apart from failing if you try to input fractional parts, this leaves the pointer in a useless state (pointing to `0x00000006`, for example, if you'd entered "6" as the last element).

You want to be reading float values into the *elements* of the `blendingArray`:

```
scanf("%f", &blendingArray[a]);
```